# Spark not able to create dataframe with single MapType as column using scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using spark version 2.2. I am trying to create a dataframe with 1 column as MapType.

I have tried following things for that:

```
scala> val mapSeq = Seq((Map(1-> 2, 11-> 22))).toDF("num")
<console>:23: error: value toDF is not a member of Seq[scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int]]
       val mapSeq = Seq((Map(1-> 2, 11-> 22))).toDF("num")
```

and

```
scala> spark.createDataFrame(List(Map("a" -> "b")), StructType(MapType(StringType, StringType)))

error: overloaded method value apply with alternatives:
  (fields: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField])org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType <and>
  (fields: java.util.List[org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField])org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType <and>
  (fields: Seq[org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField])org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType
 cannot be applied to (org.apache.spark.sql.types.MapType)
       spark.createDataFrame(List(Map("a" -> "b")), StructType(MapType(StringType, StringType)))
```

Both the methods throws error.

I tried searching and found this medium blog - https://medium.com/@mrpowers/working-with-spark-arraytype-and-maptype-columns-4d85f3c8b2b3 But it blog there is some older version of spark used.

Any Ideas on how can I create this?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46779193/2639647) answer seems to work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a Dataset of Maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46778659/how-to-create-a-dataset-of-maps)

Comment: It doesn't look like a duplicate. The answer tells about datasets and not dataframes. Is there any way to create dataframes of Maps?